# Media Query for all devices

Tags: css, media-queries, media, device, mobile-devices

Is there a media query that covers all devices as all I can find online and when researching is media queries for specific devices?
I can create media queries for lots of devices being specific to the devices however I was hoping there was a blanket media query that covered all devices. So far I have only created a media query for ipad as you can see below.

```
 @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
   #menu {
     font-weight: 400;
     display: table;
     list-style: none;
     top: 60px;
     text-align: center;
     left: -10px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
     font-size: 18px;
     height: 20px;
     z-index: 1101;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
   }
   #apDiv2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     top: 0px;
     color: #000000;
     background-color: #0263B5;
     left: 0;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Media queries are used to target CSS for specific device spec such as screen size, destiny etc.  If you just add CSS with no media query around it then it apply to all devices spec.  You should look up docs about mobile first or desktop first CSS to help you optimise your code, http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ is a start.

Answer (score 2):

Styling that pertains to all devices should not be put inside a media query at all. It should be placed either before or after the media query (or queries).

**Edit:**

For example, if (for example) your `#menu` id is the same for *all* devices, but your `#apDiv2` id needs specific styling for the iPad, then this is how you would change the CSS:

```
 #menu {
   font-weight: 400;
   display: table;
   list-style: none;
   top: 60px;
   text-align: center;
   left: -10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   font-size: 18px;
   height: 20px;
   z-index: 1101;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
 }

 @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
   #apDiv2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     top: 0px;
     color: #000000;
     background-color: #0263B5;
     left: 0;
   }
 }
```

Or, alternatively, let's assume that you want to control the positional styles for specific devices -- but all other styles are the same on *all* devices, here's how you'd do that:

```
 #menu {
   font-weight: 400;
   display: table;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   font-size: 18px;
   z-index: 1101;
   position: fixed;
 }
 #apDiv2 {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #0263B5;
 }

 @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
   #menu {
     top: 60px;
     left: -10px;
     height: 20px;
     width: 100%;
   }
   #apDiv2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand :)

Comment: @DanielNolan Joe means that - the way you've done styling before you ever heard of `media queries` is the way to go (logically it applies to every media type).

Comment: @DanielNolan, I've edited my answer to give you specific examples that I hope will make it clear.